# How to remove Terminal shortcut for Show Next Tab (Control+Tab)

Tags: terminal, keyboard

I'm using `screen` inside terminal, but when I have multiple tabs, I can't cast Ctrl+a+Tab because Ctrl+Tab switches me to next tab inside Terminal instead of switching to next tab inside `screen`.

I thought I can do this with Karabiner Elements, but I was only able to remove Ctrl+Tab from terminal.

So how do I do this? (I actually already know and just posting this so it would be easy to find for others, hopefully)

Answer (score 1):

So I found [this forum post](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040618093419348) that says how to do this you need to execute

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Show Next Tab" "nil"
```

in Terminal and restart it. It doesn't set it to `nil` (empty shortcut?) but says `N` in menu. However N letter continue to work fine and does not switch tabs.